# structure of DateTime that is a converted from json date

Tags: json, datetime, date

I'm converting a json date to DateTime & i get the following structure:
2012-02-01T04:00:00.128Z
can someone please tell me, what does the .128Z stand for?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.128` is the millisecond part of the time stamp, and `Z` stands for Zulu, which tells you that the time stamp is in UTC time (no hour shift, no daylight saving time).